# SVN serve and PySVN Error message: Expected FS format between '1' and '3'; found format '4'

Tags: python, svn, ubuntu, pysvn

For research purposes, I copied a SVN repo to my Windows machine using svnsync so I can replay on my machine without loading the actual server.

I've been using PySVN in scripts to control the revision number I want the repo to be in and have been using it fine so far. Now I got a repo from a different project and svnsync got it fine. When I try to run the script in Ubuntu I get:
`Expected FS format between '1' and '3'; found format '4'`

From what I was able to learn from other questions on StackOverFlow and elsewhere, it seems that my ubuntu pysvn is out of date for a 1.6 subversion version and would only work for 1.5. Did I understand this correctly?

Because on the [pysvn download page](http://pysvn.tigris.org/project_downloads.html) it says that "This release of pysvn has been tested against Subversion 1.5.6 and **Subversion 1.6.5**"

When I do `sudo apt-get install python-svn` it tells me that python-svn is already the newest version. So I'm assuming that PySVN doesn't support 1.6 Subversion repos.

But if I try running the exact same script on a Windows box, with only pysvn module on it (no svn installation), and the local repo files, it runs fine and I can checkout files!

So I'm confused. Why does PySVN run with FS format 4 repos on windows and not on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of ubuntu you have? 9.04? It does not have subversion 1.6 afair.

What versions do

```
dpkg -l subversion
dpkg -l python-svn
```

report?

Comment: subversion reports 1.5.4dfsg1-1ub.

python-svn reports 1.6.3-0ubuntu1.


If I update subversion it should work? I'm confused as why my Windows box (that doesn't have subversion on it and only pysvn) can use the files ok.

Comment: Yes, I think what happens is, that yout python-svn creates a repo with db version 4 and then you try to access it with svn version 1.5.4 which only understands db version up to 3.
So upgrading svn to current 1.6.x version should definitely help.

Comment: I tried `apt-get install subversion` and it returns that I have the newest version (?)

Comment: Which version of ubuntu you have? 9.04 known as jaunty? Or 9.10 known as karmic?
(you can check in file /etc/apt/sources.list)
IIRC in jaunty the latest version of subversion is 1.5. You will have to upgrade to karmic, or try to get .deb packages of newer subversion from ubuntu site and try to install it, although it may be difficult.